# Convert numpy unit8 raw array directly to float32

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In my situation I get a `numpy.ndarray` as `unit8` of size `4 * n` which represents raw binary data of `float32` entities. So 4 items together represent one `float32`. To get `float32` numbers I currently convert `uint8` raw data to a binary string and than read from this string the `float32` values.

```
np.fromstring(raw_unit8_data.tostring(), dtype='<f4')
```

Is there a possibility to do this conversion directly without converting the `uint8` data to a string first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`view`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html) to have NumPy reinterpret the raw data as the appropriate data type. For example:

```
>>> raw_unit8_data = np.array([32, 14, 135, 241], dtype='uint8')
>>> raw_unit8_data.view('<f4')
array([ -1.33752168e+30], dtype=float32)
```

This has the advantage of not using any temporary arrays or buffers (we're just changing how the memory is read) and gives the same values as your current method:

```
>>> np.fromstring(raw_unit8_data.tostring(), dtype='<f4')
array([ -1.33752168e+30], dtype=float32)
```